# magento - Update product default image to first image in image gallery

Tags: magento, php, mage

I have an import script that imports well over 2000+ products including their images. I run this script via CLI because I feel that this is the best way to go speed-wise even though I have the same import script available and executable at the magento admin as an extension. The script runs pretty well. Almost perfect! However, sometimes the `addToImageGallery` somehow malfunctions and results into some images having `No Image` as the default product image and the only other image as not selected as defaults at all. How do I mass-update all products to set the first image in the media gallery for the product to the default 'base', 'image' and 'thumbnail' image(s)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a couple of tricks on doing this (and more) on this link:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/59440/ (Thanks transio!)

Although, for Magento 1.6.2.0 (which I use), the first SQL trick there (*Trick 1 - Auto-set default base, thumb, small image to first image.*) needs a bit of modification.

On the second-to-the last-line there is a `AND ev.attribute_id IN (70, 71, 72)` part. This should point to attribute ID's which will probably not be relevant in Magento 1.6.2.0 anymore. To fix this, using any MySQL query tool (PHPMyAdmin or MySQL Query Browser), I took a look at the `catalog_product_entity_varchar` table. There should be entries like:

```
value_id, entity_type_id, attribute_id, store_id, entity_id, value
..
146649, 4, 116, 0, 1, '2'
146650, 4, 76, 0, 1, ''
146651, 4, 78, 0, 1, ''
146652, 4, 79, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'
146653, 4, 80, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'
146654, 4, 81, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'
146655, 4, 96, 0, 1, ''
146656, 4, 100, 0, 1, ''
146657, 4, 102, 0, 1, 'container2'
..
```

My money was on the group of three image paths as possible replacements. So the resulting SQL now should be:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_id IN (79, 80, 81) # <-- attribute IDs updated here
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```

So I committed to it, ran it and..  presto! All fixed! You might also want to encapsulate this in a transaction if you want. But this is out of this question's scope.

Well, this is the fix that worked for me so far! If there are any more out there, please share!

Comment: for some reason, this only set the small and thumbnail image.  for some reason, the base image isnt getting set.  i confirmed that the attribute id's in catalog_product_entity_varchar are 78, 80 and 81.  any ideas why this may be the case?

Comment: That's weird, I have used this technique literally dozens of times and not once has it failed yet.. What version are you using, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Seth, Can you please share your products upload scripts. As I am newbie and it very confusing to understand.

Answer (score 1):

There was:

> 146652, 4, 79, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'
>      146653, 4, 80, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'
>      146654, 4, 81, 0, 1, '/B/0/B05-01.jpg'

So it should be:

> AND ev.attribute_id IN (79, 80, 81) # <-- attribute IDs updated here

instead of:

> AND ev.attribute_id IN (78, 80, 81) # <-- attribute IDs updated here

Is looking for something similar.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery AS mg,
    catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value AS mgv,
    catalog_product_entity_varchar AS ev
SET ev.value = mg.value
WHERE  mg.value_id = mgv.value_id
    AND mg.entity_id = ev.entity_id
    AND ev.attribute_id IN (79, 80, 81) # <-- attribute IDs updated here
    AND mgv.position = 1;
```